# What would be the best way to handle an automatic email after a successful 'INSERT IGNORE' into a mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, email

I would like to send an email after a unique entry is added into a mysql table. I have a script that is regularly pulling data and using a SELECT IGNORE to push in data that is not a duplicate entry. I would like to send an email that reads something along the lines of "This unique entry: ENTRY NAME, was added to your table."

What I cannot figure out is if I can send emails from mysql itself, or if this is something I would handle within my python function. For example I would added it inside my function that pushes to the database, but I am not sure how to get the name of the entry that was unique.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
def uploadToDb(giant_vm_list):
    try:
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="0.0.0.0",
        user="myuser",
        password="password",
        database="my_db"
        )
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Database connection failed due to {}".format(e))
        sys.exit()

    

    for item in giant_vm_list:
        sql_query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO " + "my_db" + " (domain, domain_ip, datacenter_name, cluster_name, host_name, host_ip, resource_pool_name, vm_name) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"
        record = (item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3], item[4], item[5], item[6], item[7])
        mycursor.execute(sql_query, record)
        mydb.commit()
        #print(f"{item[0]} {item[1]} {item[2]} {item[3]} {item[4]} {item[5]} {item[6]} {item[7]}")
    print("Program ran without errors")
    #Ideally this is where I would send an email
    #Pseudo code:
    '''
    Send email: "Unique Entry with fields: 
                  domain=value, 
                  domain_ip=value, 
                  datacenter_name=value, 
                  cluster_name=value, 
                  host_name=value, 
                  host_ip=value, 
                  resource_pool_name=value, 
                  vm_name=value
                 
                  was added to 'my_db'"
    '''
    #The email would have the actual values
```

Comment: you want one email or for every entry name, but what is entry name which of he columns do you actually need?

Comment: I only want an email for the unique entry names. I do not know which ones will be unique, that is sort of what I am confused about. How can I know which entries are unique and being added to the database. So I would need all of these: domain, domain_ip, datacenter_name, cluster_name, host_name, host_ip, resource_pool_name, vm_name. Ill modify the post to be more clear

Comment: The only way you can know this is do a `SELECT domain FROM my_db` first (assuming that's the primary key), and prune your list to remove the duplicates.  That would allow you to do a normal `INSERT` instead of the somewhat wasteful `INSERT IGNORE`, because you would KNOW the records were new.

Comment: You can check [`cursor.rowcount`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-rowcount.html) after each insert. If it's 0, then the row was ignored, not inserted.

Comment: If you just use `INSERT` you can handle the duplicate key errors and know which entries were new.

Comment: @BillKarwin this has worked for me. Much appreciated.